# cert based login is not working using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to perform cert based login in SQL server but its showing login failed for user in sql server logs.

My flow is something like this:
[image]

My code is below and steps which i have followed:

**In SQL server side**

```
#Replace dns with your system name
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName test.corp.xyz.com -KeySpec KeyExchange -FriendlyName SQLCert 

#search for mmc , then go to certificates you will find above created cert 

#open sql server manager come to sql server network configuration section and right click on Protocols come to certificates tab and select above created certificate

#restart SQL server from sql server manager

#export certificate : Export-Certificate -Cert Cert:\LocalMachine\My\<Thumbprint value>-FilePath $PSScriptRoot\tstcert.cer
```

**In User Side**

```
#Check if certificate installed or not . replace thumbprint value
$present=Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | Where-Object Thumbprint -eq <Thumbprint value> | Select-Object *
if($present)
{}
else{
Copy-Item $PSScriptRoot\tstcert.cer -Destination C:\tstcert.cer
Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -FilePath C:\tstcert.cer 
}

#SQL connection 
$SqlServer= 'server name' 
$Database= 'Db Name'
$connString = "Data Source=$SqlServer;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True;"
#Create a SQL connection object
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString
#Attempt to open the connection
$conn.Open()
if($conn.State -eq "Open")
{
Write-Host "Test connection successfull"
}
```

But I'm getting login failed for user SQL server log , I might have missed out something  or might be wrong at some point as I'm new to this.

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Can you login using SQL Server Management Studio?  What credentials are in the SSMS login window?  What instance of server is in login?   You are using Integrated Security = True which means that a Window Credential is being used which also would be shown in the SSMS login window.  You can check the logs in SSMS under management in the explorer to get better understanding of error.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for reply, i have checked in logs it states login was not found, so i have added. But is there some way that  i can check if particular certificate is present then only i can login. And what changes should i do in script

Comment: You need to setup the database credentials.  The login is using TLS which uses the certificate.  The certificate to work needs to be installed in the users stores on the client.  The database credential need to be setup to allow/not allow a user.  Normally I use Windows Credentials and create a user group (or an existing Group Policy group).  Then all users in the group can access the database.  Then adding new users is done in Windows Credentials and database doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for reply what changes should i make in connection string to get connected using certificate. Any resource or something will really be helpfull. and also let me know if i'm following correct approach for creating and using certificate

Comment: No changes are needed to connection string.  Just make sure you are login to SSMS with windows credentials (not SQL) and then try a query to the database to verify you have both login and database access.  Once you get SSMS working powershell should also work.